# Get Content from Web Pages with PHP

Tags: php, get

I am working on a small project to get information from several webpages based on the HTML Markup of the page, and I do not know where to start at all.

The basic idea is of getting the Title from `<h1></h1>s`, and content from the `<p></p>s` tags and other important information that is required.

I would have to setup each case from each source for it to work the way it needs. I believe the *right* method is using `$_GET` method with PHP. The goal of the project is to build a database of information.

What is the best method to grab the information which I need?

Comment: What you're looking for is named 'scraping' and there are actually tons of solutions, libraries, wrappers and tutorials out there. Just google for "php scraper". `$_GET` is not a method, it's basically just an array holding query values - so it does not really have to do anything with your problem.

Comment: Also you should have a look to the php DOM parsers to extract correctly the desired html elements from the document/source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: [PHP's $_GET is not a method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). As you can see in the documentation $_GET is simply an array initialized with the GET's parameters *your* web server received during the current query. As such it is not what you want to use for this kind of things.

What you should look into is [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) that allows you to compose even fairly complex query, send to the destination server and retrieve the response. For example for a POST request you could do something like:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.mysite.com/tester.phtml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");

// in real life you should use something like:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
//          http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2138534/1446321)

Of course if you don't have to do any complex query but simple GET requests you can go with the PHP function [`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents)

After you received the web page content you have to parse it. IMHO the best way to do this is by using [PHP's DOM functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). How to use them should really be another question, but you can find tons of example without much effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
 $remote = file_get_contents('http://www.remote_website.html');
 $doc = new DomDocument();
 $file = @$doc->loadHTML($remote);  
 $cells = @$doc->getElementsByTagName('h1');

 foreach($cells AS $cell)
 {


    $titles[] = $cell->nodeValue ;

}

 $cells = @$doc->getElementsByTagName('p');

foreach($cells AS $cell)
 {

    $content[] = $cell->nodeValue ;

}

 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the HTML source of a page with:

```
<?php
$html= file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $html;
?>
```

Then once you ahve the structure of the page you get the request tag with substr() and strpos()

Comment: Using `substr` and `strpos` to parse HTML will cause kittens to burn in hell.